# Conversion of file size into appropriate form shows weird output

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-conversion

I am having serious problem while conversion.
The first solution I tried is the below code ::

```
    NSByteCountFormatter *formatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.allowsNonnumericFormatting = NO;

    return [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:valueFromAPI countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleMemory];
```

The second solution I tried is the below code ::

```
double convertedValue = (double)valueFromAPI;
DebugLog(@"%f",convertedValue);

int multiplyFactor = 0;

NSArray *tokens = @[@"bytes",@"KB",@"MB",@"GB",@"TB",@"PB",@"EB",@"ZB",@"YB"];

while (convertedValue >= 1024) {
    convertedValue /= 1024;
    multiplyFactor++;
}
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.0f %@",convertedValue, tokens[multiplyFactor]];
```

But both returns the same weird output. After checking for a lot of cases I found that it only happens when the file size is small.

The image displays the problem : 
[image]

The image clearly shows that the returned file sizes are in negative and in exobyte(EB) which are actually just images picked from `UIImagePickerController`.
In the second solution I found out that while converting from `long long` to double` it is converted to extended format which creates the problem.

I don't how to solve it. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual value?

Comment: @trojanfoe The values that come from the API are 1024.00, 15394.00, 482317.00, 36200.00 and they are in the form of NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString*)transformedValue:(double) valueFromAPI
{
      NSByteCountFormatter *formatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
      formatter.allowsNonnumericFormatting = NO;
      return [NSByteCountFormatter valueFromAPI countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleMemory];
}
```

I was converting the valueFromAPI to 'long long' and then to 'double' which created problem. So I converted the NSString to double and directly passed it. Now, my file sizes are showing correctly.

Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Comment: So isn't that what my answer was suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h220pqeyqn2a8v1/File%20Size%20Utility.zip?dl=0) method.

Usage :

```
#import "FileSize.h"

...

unsigned long long fileSize = ...; 
NSString *compressedFilesSize = [FileSize convertSize:fileSize];     
NSLog(@"File size : %@", compressedFilesSize);
```

Comment: Thanks @Liolik for the suggestion but, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

From conversing with you via comments you have stated that `valueFromAPI` is an `NSString *`, in which case the issue is that you are converting the *address* of the string, not the *value* it contains:

```
double convertedValue = (double)valueFromAPI;
```

You want:

```
double convertedValue = [valueFromAPI doubleValue];
```

Comment: if you try you will find that both display same output.

Comment: @SushreeSwagatika You are say both the lines in my code do the same thing?

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe. Your reply clicked the solution in my mind... :-)

Comment: Your code is correct @trojanfoe . The prob was with mine. The conversion code was written inside a NSObject class and I was converting the valueFromAPI to 'long long' and then to 'double' which created same wrong output every time....  So, instead I wrote the code in the same ViewController and it worked out fine. Thanks for your help.